# using not syntax in record selection crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, selection, record

Pardon my ignorance in advance, I'm a complete novice at Crystal Reports.

I need to select all records where a specific field (`employee.term_date`) is null. I don't seem to be able to use `ISNULL` with a date/time field.

The following will select all records that contain a value in employee.term_date, but I am looking for the opposite - all records where this field is null.

Is there any easy way to use `NOT` in the statement below, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

`{employee.term_date} > DateTime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)`

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: You can use `isnull()` with a datetime field. What makes you think you aren't able to use it that way?

Comment: What would the syntax be use ISNULL in Crystal?

Comment: The same as any other field: `isnull({table.column})`

Comment: In the Crystal Reports Record Selection formula editor, if I enter isnull {EMPLOYEE.TERM_DATE} I get the message "the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula" when I try to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below way

```
Not(CStr({employee.term_date}) like "")
```

Note: Not a tested condition...

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so very much for taking the time to post that!